# Using a single docker swarm node as an external bootstrap

Tags: docker, docker-swarm

I'm creating a docker swarm that will run in "global service" mode (i.e. a single service will run on each node).  However, I also want to bootstrap a database from only one of those nodes.

Is there a specific way that I should set up my configuration so I can set up my docker image so that:

1. External "bootstrapping" only happens on a single host.
2. But the service itself runs on all of them?

Would the solution be to create two separate services from the same image?  The first one that just has a `--replica` of `1` and does the bootstrapping, and then my global service that runs my actual service?

Comment: You can run another service with replica 1 and --restart-condition as none, so when the service ends the DB will be bootstrapped.

Comment: @TarunLalwani Yeah, this is what I figured I would do. Would you recommend using the same container/swarm to manage it, still? And just a separate entrypoint script?

Comment: Both are fine. If you create multiple environments very often I would club the init in compose. If you do it less then I would keep bootstrap service a separate one

Answer (score 0):

You can run the Database as a simple container instead of using a swarm service. Just be sure that both applications are running on the same network (https://docs.docker.com/engine/swarm/networking/).

Comment: I actually can't do this, unfortunately. The database itself is managed and is otherwise decoupled from the application.